# How to call other panels on main GUI in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

[This image is my plan that have panel1 panel2 and panel3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNOCd.jpg)

[This image is show panel1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th82Z.jpg)

**I will show panel2 when click 'next' button on panel1. How to create next button? help me please. Thank you.**

> This is my code that I use guide in matlab.

```
function varargout = testFig(varargin)

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @testFig_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @testFig_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT

% --- Executes just before testFig is made visible.
function testFig_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = testFig_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

> **Panel1**

```
% --- Browse video files.
function video_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to video (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
FileName = uigetfile('*.avi','Select the avi file');
    v = VideoReader(FileName);
    video = readFrame(v);
    imshow(video, 'Parent', handles.axes1);

% --- Browse image files.
function image_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to image (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
[FileName PathName] = uigetfile('*.jpg','Select the jpg file');
    Image = imread([PathName FileName]);
    imshow(Image, 'Parent', handles.axes1);

% --- 'next' button in panel1.
function next1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to next1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
disp(next2_Callback);
```

> **Panel2**

```
 % --- 'next' button in panel2.
    function next2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to next2 (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

    % --- 'back' button in panel2.
    function back2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to back2 (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

    % --- 'detect' button in panel3.
    function detect_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to detect (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

    % Hint: get(hObject,'Value') returns toggle state of detect

    % --- 'regiongrowing' button in panel3.
    function regiongrowing_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to regiongrowing (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

    % Hint: get(hObject,'Value') returns toggle state of regiongrowing
```

> **Panel3**

```
% --- 'back' button in panel3.
function back3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to back3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% --- 'home' button in panel3.
function home_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to home (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% --- 'finish' button in panel3.
function pushbutton8finish_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton8finish (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
```

Comment: You need to show some code and things you've tried. No ones going to do it all for you.

Comment: I add my codes. thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by setting the `Visibility` properties of the panels in the button callbacks.  Assuming you have initialized the `Visiblity` to `Off` for uipanel2 by using the Property Inspector in GUIDE you can define the callback for uipanel1's next button

```
% --- 'next' button in panel1.
function next1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to next1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
set(handles.uipanel2, 'Visible', 'On')
```

Similarly, the back buttons can set `Visible` to `Off`.

Comment: Thank you. I can create 'next' and 'back' follow your suggestion but I will back 2 step, when click 'home' then show panel1 but not have changes.